# Howto to boot an attached external hard disk (without formating)? (Solution: Repair grub easily)

Tags: boot, grub, usb-drive, bootable

I have a former internal hard drive, which I now use as external USB drive. I tried to boot from it, but it doesn't work (2 PCs tried, on my: blank screen + blinking cursor). This - I think - is normal, because to make a USB device bootable it must be prepared before the installation / during formating.

Since I don't understand, if the situation of other threads here fit on mine, please tell me:

*Is it possible to boot the system, which is already on the external drive (and which has worked, when it was an internal drive).*

My ideas were:

- use this device in a virtual machine as already installed system or try to boot from it (which doesn't work, since it's not prepared).
- change grub on the system, where I attach the external HDD

Edit: I have used `gparted` to set the partition as active / bootable. Buuuut: it is a logical partition and not the first on the HDD. When I now try to boot from the computer gets into a reset loop: right after the BIOS messages my computer restarts instead of booting.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you enable boot from USB in the BIOS?

Comment: Creek: yes, I did on both computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a partition bootable with out making an other changes. Also you may try re-installing grub on the hard disk, which should not hurt the partitions either.

Comment: coteyr: yes, thanks. gparted helped me setting "bootable". I'll try the reinstallation.

Comment: coteyr: is re-installing really that complicated? (I can't just do it from my current installation, instead I need to have a live CD. Probably because doing `grub-install` on the current booted system will add a wrong list of possibilities to boot, right?)

Comment: no it's easy. Usually you just run grub-install. `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sdX` Make sure to mount and change the device, but you can do this from a running system as well. http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/245

Comment: Wow, that was really. Should have asked earlier instead of searching the web, not understanding the man-page of grub-install, etc :)